# Bidirectional Foreign Keys Design

Tags: oracle, database-design

Say there are two tables, Company and Employee.  Employee has a foreign key to Company and Company has a foreign key to Employee.  How should I insert and delete data into these tables without getting referential integrity errors?

```
COMPANIES
 ID
 NAME
 CONTACT_EMPLOYEE_ID --FK

EMPLOYEES
 ID
 NAME
 COMPANY_ID --FK
```

I imagine this is a fairly common problem.  I have researched it but have been unable to find much information.  Perhaps the problem comes under a more common name I am not aware of.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several methods available:

1. Is the `CONTACT_EMPLOYEE_ID` column nullable? If it is, just insert company, insert employee and then update the company record.
2. You could also set one of the constraints as deferrable. You could then set the constraint as deferred, insert both records and then commit.

Answer (score 2):

There are generally 2 strategies:

- Leave one of the FKs NULL-able (and then insert NULL into that table, insert row into other table and finally update the NULL).
- [Defer](http://infolab.stanford.edu/~ullman/fcdb/oracle/or-triggers.html#deferring%20constraint%20checking) one of the FKs.

You could even leave **both** FKs NULL-able or deferrable (or even a combination of the two), so you can perform the insertion in both directions.

You could also consider placing all the EMPLOYEES fields into COMPANIES.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from the other suggestions already made, which are good (make one of the FK columns NULLable, or make the FK constraint deferrable), another one is to make the NOT NULL constraint deferrable, e.g.:

```
create table COMPANIES (
 ID number not null,
 NAME varchar2(100) not null,
 CONTACT_EMPLOYEE_ID number,
 constraint contact_not_null
   check (CONTACT_EMPLOYEE_ID not null)
   deferrable
   initially deferred
);
```

Now, you can insert a row with NULL for the employee id, insert the employee, then update companies.contact_employee_id with the new employee ID, then COMMIT.